# How Not to refresh the page after add action in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want **NOT** to refresh the page after add action in CakePHP3.

Maybe I should use ajax but if I use ajax, I don't know Model Validation of CakePHP works...

If I use ajax, will Model Validation of CakePHP work?
Or if the better way other than ajax exists, please teach me!

Comment: @DavyM Thanks for your advice! I revised the question but I don't know whether or not I understand your advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send data with ajax. An action method handles the ajax request. When you convert request data into entity (newEntity/patchEntity), the data will be validated. The ajax request and response is different from post, but coverting data to entity, validate and save are the same.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are new to using ajax with cakephp, you can see some examples and source here: http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples

Comment: Yes, I'm new to using ajax with CakePHP. I'm just looking for some example. Thanks!